# counting/filtering database-entries over multiple foreign key-relations

Tags: python, django, django-models

These are my DB-Models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20, unique = True)
    ...

class Feed(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    ...

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    read = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    feed = models.ForeignKey(Feed)
    ...
```

Every Article belongs to one Feed (source) and each Feed is in a Category.

Now, i want to create a view to display **all** categories with some meta-information, 
e.g. how many unread articles are in category x.

I tried things like this, but nothing worked:

```
categories = Category.objects.filter(feed__article__read=False)\
                             .annotate(Count('feed__article'))
```

What is the proper way to extract those information?
Especially if i want to add further information like: number of feeds in category and 
number of favored articles in one QuerySet (If possible)...

Any ideas?
Thanks.

**EDIT**: Since i had no idea how to 'solve' this problem, i've written an ugly workaround:

```
result = categories.values_list('name', 
                                'feed__title', 
                                'feed__article__title', 
                                'feed__article__read')

for i in range(0, len(result)):

    #if pointer changed to a new category
    #dump current dict to list and clear dict for the new values
    if last != result[i][0]:
        category_list.append(category_info.copy())
        category_info.clear()
        last = result[i][0]         

    if some values None:
         insert values        
    elif some other values None:
         insert values

    else:

        category_info['name'] = result[i][0]
        category_info['feed_count'] = category_info.get('feed_count', 0) + 1
        category_info['all_article_count'] = category_info.get('all_article_count', 0) + 1
        #if a article has not been read yet
        if result[i][3] == False:
            category_info['unread_article_count'] = category_info.get('unread_article_count', 0) + 1

    #if this category is the last in the result-list
    if i+1 == len(result):
        category_list.append(category_info.copy())

    i += 1
```

I am pretty sure there is a quicker and nicer way to get those information, but at least i can work with it for the moment :/

Answer (score 0):

You must label the information. You should be able to use `category.article_count` for the items in the queryset if you use the query below.

```
categories = Category.objects.filter(feed__article__read=False)\
                         .annotate(article_count=Count('feed__article'))
```

Comment: hi relekang, thanks for your supply. but how can i display all categories even if one is empty (the related feed has no articles)?

Comment: It should work. The article_count will be zero, but the category is in the queryset.